# How could I return a Spring MVC ModelAndView as String into a JSONResponse object?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

What I want to do:

- An user is prompted with a list of choices of actions to take, for example, Search User, Register New User, and so on. My idea is that when an user click pick one of the choices, an AJAX call is triggered using JQuery and then the method is executed, returning a JSONResponse.

A JSONResponse is just a simple object with 2 variables: status as String, and result as Object, as following:

```
public class JSONResponse {
private String status = null;
private Object result = null;


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public Object getResult() {
    return result;
}
public void setResult(Object result) {
    this.result = result;
}       
}
```

However, sometimes I want to return a ModelAndView into this response. For example: when the user search for a user, the application searches for it and then return a ModelAndView with a list of possible users. One way to achieve this is to render a ModelAndView as String and then put it as result into a JSONResponse object. The problem is that how can I render a ModelAndView as String to put it into the JSONReponse?

PS: I'm using Tomcat 7, JDK 6, Spring MVC 3.0 with Tiles 2, Jackson (to convert java objects to JSON)

Comment: What you mean by "pass ModelAndView" as JSONRespose? and why do you want to do it?

Comment: And why not to just return ModelAndView as ModelAndView and let spring handle it? (resolving it and rendering new page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question what I understand is sometimes you need to return json and sometimes model and view because you are passing search list using model and view.
 Ideally these two things must be handled in different method but as you want to handle it in same method then your method must return **String** instead of **ModelAndView** so that you can return json data. And search list which you want to send you can put it into session and then you will get it on JSP page (because of Session Scope).

Method will look somewhat like this :

```
public @ResponseBody
String methodName(HttpServletRequest request) {


       if(jsondata){ //Wants to send json data
       return jsonFinalData.toString();
       }else{
       //store search list in session
        return view_name;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return ModelAndView if needed else write to a response stream.

```
public ModelAndView getSomething(HttpServletResponse response) { 
    // perform your logic

    if(obj returned must be a json) {
        try {
              new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter().write(obj, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, new ServletServerHttpResponse(response));
        } catch(Exception e) {
              logger.error("Error while serializing to JSON string.");
        }

        return null;
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView("yourview");
    }
}
```